# Cannot access wp admin on another computer in local network

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have created a wordpress website on a wampserver 3.2.6 and wanted to access the website, as well as admin panel from another device(pc) on a local network but I get an error (`err_refuse_to_connect`). I have read some topics and tested some solutions and it partially works. The page loads when I type ip address of the server where the website is, but only text loads, without images and I cannot access the admin panel. I have configured `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www
  <Directory "D:/wamp64/www">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I have created a rule in firewall to allow inbound connections on port 80 and added ip address of a computer I want to connect in `hosts` file. Is there any simple and clear solution for this?

Comment: what are your site url and home url in wordpress settings?

Comment: @GrafiCode It's http://localhost/psgs

Comment: I think you should change that with your LAN IP address, something like `http://192.168.0.50/psgs`

Comment: Thank you @GrafiCode it worked :D Somehow I have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your wordpress setting's URL to a Local IP address.

localhost will always goto 127.0.0.1 but I doubt